# Convert one dataframe's format and check if each row exits in another dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Given a small dataset `df1` as follow:

```
  city  year quarter
0   sh  2019      q4
1   bj  2020      q3
2   bj  2020      q2
3   sh  2020      q4
4   sh  2020      q1
5   bj  2021      q1
```

I would like to create date range in quarter from `2019-q2` to `2021-q1` as column names, then check if each row in `df1`'s `year` and `quarter` for each city exist in `df2`.

If they exist, then return `y`s for that cell, otherwise, return `NaN`s.

The final result will like:

```
  city  2019-q2  2019-q3 2019-q4 2020-q1 2020-q2 2020-q3 2020-q4 2021-q1
0   bj      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN       y       y     NaN       y
1   sh      NaN      NaN       y       y     NaN     NaN       y     NaN
```

To create column names for `df2`:

```
pd.date_range('2019-04-01', '2021-04-01', freq = 'Q').to_period('Q')
```

How could I achieve this in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) on `city` and the string concatenation of the `year` and `quarter` columns:

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df['city'], df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['quarter'])
```

`new_df`:

```
col_0  2019-q4  2020-q1  2020-q2  2020-q3  2020-q4  2021-q1
city                                                       
bj           0        0        1        1        0        1
sh           1        1        0        0        1        0
```

---

We can convert to `bool`, [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) `False` and `True` to be the correct values, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to add missing columns, and cleanup axes and index to get exact output:

```
col_names = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2021-04-01', freq='Q').to_period('Q')

new_df = (
    pd.crosstab(df['city'], df['year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['quarter'])
        .astype(bool)  # Counts to boolean
        .replace({False: np.NaN, True: 'y'})  # Fill values
        .reindex(columns=col_names.strftime('%Y-q%q'))  # Add missing columns
        .rename_axis(columns=None)  # Cleanup axis name
        .reset_index()  # reset index
)
```

`new_df`:

```
  city  2019-q1  2019-q2  2019-q3 2019-q4 2020-q1 2020-q2 2020-q3 2020-q4 2021-q1
0   bj      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN       y       y     NaN       y
1   sh      NaN      NaN      NaN       y       y     NaN     NaN       y     NaN
```

---

DataFrame and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ['sh', 'bj', 'bj', 'sh', 'sh', 'bj'],
    'year': [2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021],
    'quarter': ['q4', 'q3', 'q2', 'q4', 'q1', 'q1']
})
```

Comment: Sorry, my miskakes, I think we need to use `pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2021-04-01', freq = 'Q').to_period('Q')` as column names of `df2`, since in `df1`, the date may not be successive. For example, `2020-q2` could be missed both for `bj` and `sh`.

Comment: Updated my answer to add a `reindex` to fill missing values from the date range. See if that works (it's the second code block).